# CSV line splitting into an array

Tags: java, csv, split

I have a CSV file that contains a line:

```
SHIELA,ABIJAY,,,shiela@abijay.com,Shiela123,,43 123 STREET,,MEDFORD,MA ,2155,,,,617-874-4248,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20847, INAC,8101969,,,,,,,`
```

Using the split am splitting the values into an array

```
def fields = line.split(",")
```

I am getting

```
[SHIELA, ABIJAY, , , shiela@abijay.com, Shiela123, , 43 BOWER STREET, , MEDFORD, MA , 2155, , , , 617-874-4248, 0, 0, 0, , , , , 0, 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 20847,  INAC, 8101969]
```

But in line I have few more commas after 8101969. How do I get that commas also in that array?

Comment: Just curious: are you sure you're talking about Java ("`def fields = line.split(",")`")?

Comment: 1) Use a CSV parser. 2) *"Plz help me

Nimmy"*  Please spell **all 6** letters the word 'please', and don't include such noise in questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this particular problem, do

```
def fields = line.split(",", -1)
```

Generally speaking though, I agree with @npinti; It may be a good idea to consider using a CSV library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to process CSV files I would recommend you use something more robust (than just the `.split`) such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#what-is-opencsv):

> opencsv is a very simple csv (comma-separated values) parser library
>   for Java.

A very short tutorial is available [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read).

Answer (score 1):

Please see [JavaDoc for split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). If there is only one parameter, empty trailing Strings are discarded. If there is a non-positive second parameter,

> then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

So your problem would be solved using:

```
def fields = line.split(",", -1)
```